# My Java Swing JPanel will only strech to the size of one monitor on a two monitor display

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, stretch, multiple-monitors

My JPanel will stretch between two monitors just fine, but will not stretch to the size of both monitors. It stops at the size of one monitor. How can I fix this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I am not sure what to display for this particular problem. My class extends JPanel.

Comment: I am not sure you even clicked the link.  Don't extend panel unless custom painting.

Comment: I was referring to what code to display. It is all vanilla boiler plate code for getting a JPanel on the screen. There should be a property to set in Java that would allow it to stretch the size of multiple monitors.

Comment: *"I was referring to what code to display."*  It is explained in the link.  *"There should be.."* ..free beer, for having to deal with people who cannot manage to click a link.

Comment: The answer is as simple as, "It should by default"

Comment: JFrame.  A JPanel sits inside a JFrame.  The JFrame is what you must be resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that JPanels will by default stretch across multiple monitors. There is something about the proprietary framework that my software runs on that is blocking that.